# Calling back a FormDialog a defined number of times

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to create a bot that will ask questions to the user. At launch, the bot asks which choice the user would take :

1. Start a quiz (he will have to choose the theme and the difficulty of the quiz after) ;
2. See the score he got in the last quiz ;
3. Reset the score.

The content of the quiz is in a XML file. I already stored the questions and the answers associated in a struct.

The FormBuilder is :

```
[Serializable]
public class QuizQuestionsLoader
{
    public QuizQuestion Question { get; set; }

    public static IForm<QuizQuestionsLoader> QuestionLoaderForm(QuizQuestion question)
    {
        return new FormBuilder<QuizQuestionsLoader>()
            .Field(new FieldReflector<QuizQuestionsLoader>(nameof(Question))
                .SetType(null)
                .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                {
                    field
                        .AddDescription(state.Question.QuestionText, state.Question.QuestionText)
                        .AddTerms(state.Question.QuestionText, state.Question.QuestionText);

                    return true;
                }))
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

And so, I did an IDialog with a switch that determine which choice the user took. The DefaultCase will be activated if the user chose to start a quiz :

```
new DefaultCase<QuizChoices?, IDialog<string>>((context, value) =>
                {
                    return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(QuizStart.QuizForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart))
                        .Select(c => c.category)
                        .ContinueWith(async (ctx, res) =>
                        {
                            CategoryOptions? category = await res;
                            IList<QuizQuestion> questions = QuestionsLoader.LoadQuestions(category.Value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();

                            QuizQuestion currentQuestion = questions[0];
                            var questionsDialogs = Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(() => { return QuizQuestionsLoader.QuestionLoaderForm(currentQuestion); })).PostToUser();

                            for (int i = 1; i < questions.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                currentQuestion = questions[i];

                                questionsDialogs.ContinueWith(async (forctx, fores) =>
                                {
                                    await fores;
                                    return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(() => { return QuizQuestionsLoader.QuestionLoaderForm(currentQuestion); }));
                                }).PostToUser();
                            }

                            return Chain.Return(questionsDialogs).Unwrap();
                    })
                    .ContinueWith(async (ctx, res) =>
                    {
                        await res;
                        return Chain.Return("Quiz fini !");
                    });
                })
```

I want to display 10 questions to the user, that's why I thought that recall the FormBuilder was a good idea, because I don't see how I can do that in another way. When I build and run this, after the choice of the difficulty, the Bot Framework emulator sends a 500 internal server error.

That's why I tried to recall a "test" FormBuilder, which is composed whith a simple message and three choices, to see if I can recall the FormDialog with a for loop. 
Here is the FormBuilder :

```
public enum TestOptions
{
    A, B, C
}

[Serializable]
public class Test
{
    public TestOptions? choice;

    public static IForm<Test> TestForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<Test>()
            .Message("Test")
            .Field(nameof(choice))
            .Build();
    }
}
```

And here is the IDialog :

```
return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(Test.TestForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart))
                        .ContinueWith(async(ctx, res) =>
                        {
                            await res;
                            var testDialog = Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(() => { return Test.TestForm(); })).PostToUser();

                            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                            {
                                testDialog.ContinueWith<Test, Test>(async (forctx, fores) =>
                                {
                                    await fores;
                                    return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(Test.TestForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart));
                                });
                            }

                            return Chain.Return(testDialog);
                        })
```

With this, the FormDialog will display once, but I saw that the for loop is executed. However, the testDialog variable is null.

So, do you know how I can proceed to recall correctly my FormBuilder to have 10 questions on the Bot Framework Emulator ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a sample that illustrates how to iterate over questions in a quiz with this [commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/b05d1c4ff8056204368c3cc602754c36222034fc#diff-671ec50ba4f85003efd4c6b1a3f8da28R341).  It uses a chainable dialog named FoldDialog to invoke a series of dialogs in sequence and aggregate the responses:

```
var quiz = Chain
            .PostToChain()
            .Select(_ => "how many questions?")
            .PostToUser()
            .WaitToBot()
            .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Text))
            .Select(count => Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(index => Chain.Return($"question {index + 1}?").PostToUser().WaitToBot().Select(m => m.Text)))
            .Fold((l, r) => l + "," + r)
            .Select(answers => "your answers were: " + answers)
            .PostToUser();
```

It allows the creation of a script like this:

```
"hello",
"how many questions?",
"3",
"question 1?",
"A",
"question 2?",
"B",
"question 3?",
"C",
"your answers were: A,B,C"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you for you answer Will Pornoy !

However, I already succeed to resolve my issue before your answer, like this :

```
new DefaultCase<QuizChoices?, IDialog<string>>((context, value) =>
                {
                    return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(QuizStart.QuizForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart))
                        .Select(c => new QuizParameters
                        {
                            CategoryParameter = c.category.Value.ToString(),
                            DifficultyParameter = c.difficulty.Value.ToString()
                        })
                        .ContinueWith<QuizParameters?, int>(async (ctx, res) =>
                        {
                            await res;

                            IList<QuizQuestion> questions = QuestionsLoader.LoadQuestions(QuizParameters.CategoryParameter, QuizParameters.DifficultyParameter).ToList();
                            return new QuizQuestionsLoader(questions);
                        })
```

Where `QuizParameter` is a struct which contains the category and the difficulty choices of the user.
I get simply an `IList` which contains the questions text and its answers.

Finally, I pass it to a new object `QuizQuestionLoader`. In this class, I make some methods :

```
[Serializable]
public class QuizQuestionsLoader : IDialog<int>
{ 
    public static int Score { get; private set; }

    private IList<QuizQuestion> problems;
    private QuizQuestion theQuestion;

    private int index;      
    private int jokerCount = 2;
    private const string jokerAnswerText = "Utiliser un joker";

    public QuizQuestionsLoader(IList<QuizQuestion> problems)
    {
        this.problems = problems;
    }
```

A `Task` method which is called each time the quiz is started :

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        problems.Shuffle();

        DisplayQuestion(context);
    }
```

An `DisplayQuestion` method overload (the first is for the case where no joker left) :

```
private void DisplayQuestion(IDialogContext context)
    {
        DisplayQuestion(context, false);
    }

    private void DisplayQuestion(IDialogContext context, bool useJoker)
    {
        theQuestion = problems[index];
        string questionText = theQuestion.QuestionText;
        IList<Answer> answers = theQuestion.Answers.ToList();

        if (useJoker)
        {
            IList<Answer> randomBadAnswers = answers.Where(a => !a.IsCorrect).ToList();
            randomBadAnswers.Shuffle();
            randomBadAnswers = randomBadAnswers.Take(2).ToList();

            answers = answers.Except(randomBadAnswers).ToList();
        }
        else if (jokerCount > 0)
        {
            Answer jokerAnswer = new Answer
            {
                AnswerText = $"{jokerAnswerText} ({jokerCount}) restant(s)"
            };

            answers.Add(jokerAnswer);  
        }

        PromptDialog.Choice(context, CheckResponseAsync, answers, questionText, null, 0, PromptStyle.Auto);
    }
```

AND, finally, the loop that will reload this process until the 10 questions are displayed :

```
public async Task CheckResponseAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Answer> argument)
    {
        Answer answer = await argument;

        if (answer.AnswerText.StartsWith(jokerAnswerText))
        {
            jokerCount--;
            await context.PostAsync("Suppression de deux mauvaises réponses...");
            DisplayQuestion(context, true);
        }
        else
        { 
            await context.PostAsync(answer.IsCorrect ? "Bonne réponse !" : "Mauvaise réponse !");
            index++;

            Answer goodAnswer = theQuestion.Answers.First(a => a.IsCorrect);

            if (answer.AnswerText == goodAnswer.AnswerText)
            {
                Score++;
            }

            if (index < problems.Count)
            {
                DisplayQuestion(context);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Votre score est de {Score}");
                context.Done(Score);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help ! :)